# CSS loop an animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS but I have encountered a problem:

```
<style style="text/css">
    div.slide-slow {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div.slide-slow div.inner {
        animation: slide-slow 30s;
        margin-top: 0%;
    }

    @keyframes slide-slow {
        from {
            margin-left: 100%;
        }

        to {
            margin-left: 0%;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="slide-slow">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://www.html.am/images/html-codes/marquees/fish-swimming.gif" alt="Swimming fish">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this CSS to loop and not just stop when it is done. Is it possible to make a CSS function to loop?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Tushar I want it to loop right now when it is done the image that slides in  gets "stuck" in the left corner https://gyazo.com/b8a69abb539ed04c5a15df87f13e6e87

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`animation-iteration-count: infinite`](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/animation-iteration-count/). Limit the loop with a number value.

```html
<style style="text/css">
  div.slide-slow {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.slide-slow div.inner {
    animation: slide-slow 3s;
    margin-top: 0%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  @keyframes slide-slow {
    from {
      margin-left: 100%;
    }
    to {
      margin-left: 0%;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="slide-slow">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.html.am/images/html-codes/marquees/fish-swimming.gif" alt="Swimming fish">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Additional:** For Ismael's suggestion to achieve back and forth animation with a flip effect, you can make use of [`rotateY(180deg)`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/rotateY%28%29). Contrary to flip at a static place/position, it is better to rotate the fish as if it is moving with the flow of water current to backwards(normal animation). [`ease-in-out`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/animation-timing-function) can help maintaining the timing function better. I have used `width: 40vw` for the rotate function to slightly be responsive/view port dependent and not rotate with too much offset.

Play around with the margin and width values to achieve suitable animation.

```html
<style style="text/css">
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  div.slide-slow {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.slide-slow div.inner {
    animation: slide-slow 15s;
    margin-top: 0%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    width: 40vw;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  @keyframes slide-slow {
    0% {
      margin-left: 85%;
    }
    25% {
      margin-left: 20%;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% {
      margin-left: -25%;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      transform-origin: center center;
    }
    75% {
      margin-left: 50%;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    100% {
      margin-left: 85%;
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="slide-slow">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJAsS.gif" alt="Swimming fish">
  </div>
</div>
```

(image source: http://www.html.am/images/html-codes/marquees/fish-swimming.gif)

Answer (score 10):

You can add the infinite call into the normal `animation` CSS property.

To make the animation smoother, I would also recommend having an extra step which makes the fish go off the screen, it just completes the animation otherwise the fish just disappears.

```css
div.slide-slow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.slide-slow div.inner {
  animation: slide-slow 3s infinite;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
@keyframes slide-slow {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-slow">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="http://www.html.am/images/html-codes/marquees/fish-swimming.gif" alt="Swimming fish">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add this property:

```
 div.slide-slow div.inner {
      animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think just adding this code will help you..
This will add the animation direction also..

**CSS**

```
div.slide-slow {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

div.slide-slow div.inner {
   animation: slide-slow 3s;
   margin-top: 0%;
   animation-direction: alternate;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```